# Unable to export traces to OpenTelemetry Collector on Kubernetes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kubernetes, open-telemetry, exporter

I am using the opentelemetry-ruby otlp exporter for auto instrumentation:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-ruby/tree/main/exporter/otlp

The otel collector was installed as a daemonset:
https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/tree/main/charts/opentelemetry-collector

I am trying to get the OpenTelemetry collector to collect traces from the Rails application. Both are running in the same cluster, but in different namespaces.

We have enabled auto-instrumentation in the app, but the rails logs are currently showing these errors:

`E, [2022-04-05T22:37:47.838197 #6] ERROR -- : OpenTelemetry error: Unable to export 499 spans`

I set the following env variables within the app:

```
OTEL_LOG_LEVEL=debug
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://0.0.0.0:4318
```

I can't confirm that the application can communicate with the collector pods on this port.
Curling this address from the rails/ruby app returns "Connection Refused". However I am able to curl `http://<OTEL_POD_IP>:4318` which returns 404 page not found.

From inside a pod:

```
# curl http://localhost:4318/
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 4318: Connection refused

# curl http://10.1.0.66:4318/
404 page not found
```

This helm chart created a daemonset but there is no service running. Is there some setting I need to enable to get this to work?

I confirmed that otel-collector is running on every node in the cluster and the daemonset has HostPort set to 4318.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is with this setting:

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT=http://0.0.0.0:4318
```

Imagine your pod as a stripped out host itself. Localhost or 0.0.0.0 of your pod, and you don't have a collector deployed in your pod.

You need to use the address from your collector. I've checked the examples available at the [shared repo](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-helm-charts/tree/main/charts/opentelemetry-collector/examples) and for `agent-and-standalone` and `standalone-only` you also have a k8s resource of type Service.

With that you can use the full service name (with namespace) to configure your environment variable.
Also, the Environment variable now is called `OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT`, so you will need something like this:

```
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT=<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>
```

Comment: Thank you that worked. The OpenTelemetry errors have stopped. 
However I had to use this endpoint, the service name itself wasn't resolvable:
<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local:<service-port>

In addition, the env variable I changed was:
OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_TRACES_ENDPOINT.
 The non-specific OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT didn't seem to make any difference.

This helm chart should have clearer documentation that both the standalone collector AND daemonset agent need to enabled.

Comment: Thx @alig227, I'll update the answer with your insights.

Answer (score 4):

The correct solution is to use the [Kubernetes Downward API](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/) to fetch the node IP address, which will allow you to export the traces directly to the daemonset pod within the same node:

```yaml
  containers:
  - name: my-app
    image: my-image
    env:
    - name: HOST_IP
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: status.hostIP
    - name: OTEL_EXPORTER_OTLP_ENDPOINT
      value: http://$(HOST_IP):4318
```

Note that using the deployment's service as the endpoint (`<service-name>.<namespace>.svc.cluster.local`) is incorrect, as it effectively bypasses the daemonset and sends the traces directly to the deployment, which makes the daemonset useless.

Comment: Thanks for adding this answer. I was wondering exactly why you'd use a `Service` with a `Daemonset`. It seems like you'd rather have the otel collector as a `Deployment` in that case.

Comment: If you're not using the logs and metrics features of the collector then it is better to use a deployment rather than a daemonset, see https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-collector/issues/5405